# Match arrays in parallel Python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have three arrays, in which each entrance is timestamped. I give a simple 1-dimensional example:

```
A=[1 4 5 2 6 3 4 8]
B=[1 2 3 4]
C=[4 5 6 7 8]
```

My script should give as a result two arrays, matching elements from A to B and from A to C, for instance:

```
new_B=[1 2 3 4
       1 2 3 4]

new_C=[4 5 6 7 8
       4 5 6 - 8]
```

where the second line added corresponds to the elements from A, now sorted. As you can see, it could happen that some elements are missing in A. In that case, a "-" should be added.

Any ideas on which is the best way to do this?

Comment: The lack of commas and use of `array` suggests these might be `numpy` arrays, rather than standard `list` structures. Is that correct?

Comment: I realized I oversimplified my question. In fact, I have three lists of arrays, where the criteria for two arrays to match is (1) the matching of one of the elements of the array (integer numbers) and (2) that the difference in the timestamps contained in the arrays is lower than a certain threshold...

Comment: You are changing the question, while still making it unclear. The 3 answers bellow respond your current question. If your data is not actually what you showed up, either properly update the question with real data, or even better, open a new question with real data.

Comment: Considering how much different your question on real data is from the current question, I think it's more appropriate to create a new question. Read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293445/2243104) why you shouldn't change the question content now. Quote, "*Any time an edit would invalidate existing answers, the action to take is to revert it to a point in which the answers aren't invalidated.*"

Answer (score 2):

I would use python `sets` to make more efficient to search in `A` for large arrays, and list comprehension to speed up the search:

```
def match_arrays(A,B):
    A = set(A)
    return [B, [b if b in A else '-' for b in B]]
```

And then:

```
>>> match_arrays([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
>>> match_arrays([1,2,3], [1,4,3])
[[1, 2, 3], [1, '-', 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
def match_array(A, B):
    matches = []
    for elem in B:
        if elem in A:
            matches.append(elem)
        else:
            matches.append("-")
    return [B, matches]
```

It returns a list, containing two lists themselves: the original list to be matched and the matching results.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
>>> def compare(a,b):
    result = [b,[]]
    for x in b:
        if x in a:
            result[1].append(x)
        else:
            result[1].append('-')
    return result

>>> compare(A,B)
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> compare(A,C)
[[4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [4, 5, 6, '-', 8]]
>>>
```

Even with list comprehension, it is possible to do it:

```
>>> A=[1, 4, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4, 8]
>>> B=[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> C=[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> [B,[x if x in A else '-' for x in B]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> [C,[x if x in A else '-' for x in C]]
[[4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [4, 5, 6, '-', 8]]
```